# Gap between two 3D objects in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, game-mechanics, transformation

Quick question related to Unity: if I have two objects (A and B) to create some tunnel, how can I make a constant gap? I thought of having A and B instantiated with a random value to start with; however, it will not be constant gap. So I was wondering what other ways are (as I'm reading now, there is Vector3.Distance method; but implementing it makes it a little bit more confusing). The idea is to have your player go through to this gap constant of object A and B.

Picture as an example:[image]
However, the gaps have inconsistencies because they are not clean. Sometimes there are really close together and the red ball cannot even go through (like the next image)[image]

This is the code example that I have at this moment:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] obstaclesPrefab;
    private float startDelay = 2;
    private float repeatRate = 2;
    private PlayerControl playerControllerScript;
    float gap = 4;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerControllerScript = GameObject.Find("Tomato").GetComponent<PlayerControl>();
        InvokeRepeating("SpawnObstacle", startDelay, repeatRate);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    void SpawnObstacle()
    {
        int obstaclesIndex = Random.Range(0, obstaclesPrefab.Length);
        float randomY = Random.Range(-1.0f, 2.0f);
        float randomY2 = Random.Range(-1.0f, 2.0f);
        Vector3 pipe = new Vector3(25, randomY * gap, -10);
        Vector3 pipe2 = new Vector3(25, randomY2 * gap, -10);
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(pipe2, pipe);
        if (playerControllerScript.gameOver == false)
        {
            Instantiate(obstaclesPrefab[obstaclesIndex], pipe2, obstaclesPrefab[obstaclesIndex].transform.rotation);
            Instantiate(obstaclesPrefab[obstaclesIndex], pipe, obstaclesPrefab[obstaclesIndex].transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm open to suggestions as I'm getting started with game development and learning too. Thank you for time and have a great day!

EDIT: Thank you DMGregory for such a simple solution and help. I was just tired and my brain was mush. This totally did the trick!

Comment: Did you consider doing just one random roll for each pair of pipes, then adding a constant offset to get two positions from that single roll?

Comment: Well, I guess I was just tired. Your thought process helped me a lot and I was able to fix it :). I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: If you've solved your problem, be sure to post your solution as an Answer below. This can help future developers who are trying to solve similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you DMGregory for such a simple solution and help. I was just tired and my brain was mush. This totally did the trick!

Code example:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] obstaclesPrefab;
    private float startDelay = 2;
    private float repeatRate = 2;
    private PlayerControl playerControllerScript;
    float gap = 7.0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerControllerScript = GameObject.Find("Tomato").GetComponent<PlayerControl>();
        InvokeRepeating("SpawnObstacle", startDelay, repeatRate);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    void SpawnObstacle()
    {
        int obstaclesIndex = Random.Range(0, obstaclesPrefab.Length);
        float randomY = Random.Range(-1.5f, 2.5f);
        Vector3 randomHeight = new Vector3(25, randomY, -10); //CHANGED HERE
        Vector3 randomHeight2 = new Vector3(25, randomY + gap, -10); //CHANGED HERE (I'm adding gap, not multiplying it)
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(randomHeight, randomHeight2);
        if (playerControllerScript.gameOver == false)
        {
            Instantiate(obstaclesPrefab[obstaclesIndex], randomHeight, obstaclesPrefab[obstaclesIndex].transform.rotation);
            Instantiate(obstaclesPrefab[obstaclesIndex], randomHeight2, obstaclesPrefab[obstaclesIndex].transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now this answer just says "thank you" — it does not show what you changed to solve the problem, so it won't be very helpful to future readers trying to solve the same problem. Don't worry about gratitude — worry about clearly sharing usable game development solutions.

Comment: Added, thank you :)

Comment: Code helps. Code plus an explanation of what you changed and why that solves the problem is even better.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as "Accepted" if it solved your problem, by clicking the checkmark icon in the top left.